# Keep getting an error when I subtract across two dictionaries : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def duration_in_mins(datum, city):
    """
    Takes as input a dictionary containing info about a single trip (datum) and
    its origin city (city) and returns the trip duration in units of minutes.

    Remember that Washington is in terms of milliseconds while Chicago and NYC
    are in terms of seconds. 

    HINT: The csv module reads in all of the data as strings, including numeric
    values. You will need a function to convert the strings into an appropriate
    numeric type when making your transformations.
    see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
    """
    datum_n = round(float(example_trips['NYC']['tripduration'])/60,4)
    print(datum_n)
    datum_c = round(float(example_trips['Chicago']['tripduration'])/60,4)
    print(datum_c)
    datum_w = round(float(example_trips['Washington']['Duration (ms)'])/60000,4)
    print(datum_w)

    duration={'NYC': datum_n,
              'Chicago': datum_c,
              'Washington': datum_w}

    print(duration)

    return duration

tests = {'NYC': 13.9833,
     'Chicago': 15.4333,
     'Washington': 7.1231}print(duration)

**for city in tests:
assert abs(duration_in_mins(example_trips[city], city) - tests[city]) < .001**
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-90486a3cfc17> in <module>()
     45 
     46 for city in tests:
---> 47     assert abs(duration_in_mins(example_trips[city], city) - tests[city]) < .001

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `dict` with a `float`. Negating one from the another is not possible as an arithmetic operation.

Specifically:

- `duration_in_mins(example_trips[city], city)` returns a `dict` object.
- `tests[city]` returns a `float` object.

My guess is that you want:

```
duration_in_mins(example_trips[city], city)[city] - tests[city]
```

Comment: @Joseph, feel free too accept the answer if it helped (tick on the left).